# Debugging multiple servers at once

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have multiple Node API servers that I'd like to debug at the same time (breakpoints et cetera). Each server lives in separate directories as siblings, and I have each directory open in separate windows. I can attach a debugger to one server (call it AAA), but when I try attaching to the second server (call it BBB), I get the following error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:5858
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
    at Agent.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1304:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1428:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:83:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Is there no way to debug multiple processes at once? I tried editing `.vscode/launch.json` to change the port the debugger should attach to, but that didn't seem to work. The debugger looked like it couldn't find something and just timed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to run one server with `--debug-brk=5959` (defaults to `5858`), then edit `.vscode/launch.json` to change the `port` to `5959` also. Start both servers, open both code bases in separate Code windows and start debugging each like normal.

A secondary issue I had was getting the flag passed on to Node. My start script points to `rejoice -c manifest.json -p .`. `rejoice` doesn't accept `--debug-brk` or pass it along to Node, so I added a debug script: `node --debug-brk=5959 node_modules/.bin/rejoice -c manifest.js -p .` as a workaround.